# Regex Python based on internal structures if they exists

Tags: python, regex

I have a structure like this

`[[word test]] or [[word | word2 ]] or [[word test2 # word]]] ...`

I need to extract everything before the # and the |, if they exist, and ignore what is after. If they don't exists, return everything between the braces.

So the results for the examples above will be:

```
word test
word
word test2
```

I have

`variable =  re.findall(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', docs[doc], re.IGNORECASE)`

but this is not extracting what is before `#` or `|`.

Comment: Share your code in the question.

Comment: I have already. Now I have added the variable name too, if that was what you meant :)

Comment: To match `[[word: [[word test]]]]`, the regex should support recursion, that is possible with PyPi regex module only, not `re`

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the tip, I will look for. But on the example that you post it ('\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)(?:[:|](.*?))?]]'), saying that is no recursion its not working because for the [[word test: word1]] its outputting word test and word1, and I need just word1 on this case. On the cases that are : or | on the string I have to get just the second string

Comment: I will remove the recursion of the question, there are just few few cases, is not necessary

Comment: So, you want https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/2? `\[\[(?:(?!\[\[).)*?(?:[:|](.*?))?]]`? If there are no `]` and `[` inside you may also use `\[\[[^][]*?(?:[:|]([^][]*))?]]`, see https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/3

Comment: Thanks! But in your case, things like [[word:word2]] are not being returned as ''word:word2", and I am not managing how to change. Can you help? :)

Comment: For your sample you could probably just use [`(?<=\[\[)[^]|#]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/IOFWEo/1/) maybe put more sample input :)

Comment: Your comment and the question update are inconsistent. So, do you want `\[\[\s*([^][]*?)\s*(?:[#|][^][]*)?]]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/5))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks you! It was exactly what I need!! I will try to make the question clearer, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the strings between `[[` and `]]` contain no `[` and `]` and no nested brackets, you may use

```
re.findall(r'\[\[\s*([^][]*?)\s*(?:[#|][^][]*)?]]', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/5).

**Regex details**

- `\[\[` - a `[[` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^][]*?)` - Group 1 (what will be returned by `re.findall`):
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:[#|][^][]*)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `#` or `|` followed with 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]]` - a `]]` substring.

If the part you need to extract may contain `[` or `]` you may use

```
r'\[\[\s*((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\s*(?:[#|].*?)?]]'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/6). The `(?:(?!\[\[).)*?` will match any char, 0 or more but as few as possible, that does not start  a `[[` char sequence. `.*?` will match any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! But still a question, just to learn. If I wanted to return the things after the # and the | what should I do? I tried to change to ([][^]*?) , imagining that will be group 2 to be returned, but It doesn't work. In your answer, that was I needed, returns all before the #  and |

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira No idea why it did not work, `\[\[\s*([^][]*?)\s*(?:[#|]\s*([^][]*))?]]` [must work](https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/8).

Comment: It worked like a charm for my original question!
I just wanted to know what should I change if I want to get just the second part (just the word after the | and the #, on my original question I asked for the word before the | and the # ). It's just for curiosity

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira This is a matter of where and how many capturing groups you use, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwuj0I/9).

Comment: Ok, now I see! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try this Regular Expression ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWIaRc/3)) too:

```
r'\[+\s*(.*?)\s*(?:[#|].*?)?]+'
```

The complete example will be this.

```
import re

_input = [ 
    '[[word test]]'
    ,'[[word | word2 ]]'
    ,'[[word test2 # word]]' 
]

_re = r'\[+\s*(.*?)\s*(?:[#|].*?)?]+'

output = [ re.findall(_re, _)[0] for _ in _input ]
print(output) # ['word test', 'word', 'word test2']
```

I hope this work.

**Explanation**:

```
'\[+' and ']+'
```

Will be focus on the brackets.

```
\s* (group_necessary) \s* (group_unnecessary)?
```

The set '(?:)' Will not take in consideration the 'group_unnecessary', rewriting:

```
\s* (group_necessary) \s* (?:group_unnecessary)?
```

-

```
'(.*?)'
```

Will fetch entirely the 'group_necessary'.

```
'([#|].*?)?'
```

Will fetch '#' or '|' and '(.*?)', translated as the 'group_unnecessary' zero or more time because of the last '?'.